# Calculate total experimental time for each sample

Tags: r, datetime, for-loop, time, difference

I am trying to calculate cumulative time between experiment initiation and each temperature measurement I made during an experiment. My experiment has 50+ samples (i.e. A1,A2,B1,B2 ect) and each sample was initiated at a different time/day.

I want to treat time as a continuous variable so I need to calculate the total (cumulative time in hours) for each temp measurement, as indicated by a total time variable (below).

Is there a way to do this without telling R the start and end time for each sample? How can I get cumulative time for each temperature measurement?

An example of how the data looks is shown below:

```
Date    Time    Sample  Temp    **Total Time**
2017-06-28  13:58   A1  13.67870139 0
2017-06-29  16:08   A1  13.34256319 (time between 06-28 13:58 and 06-29 16:08)
2017-06-30  07:32   A1  12.84005139 (time between 06-28 13:58 and 06-30 07:32)
2017-06-30  19:14   A1  12.84005139 ect
2017-07-01  07:40   A1  11.83983472 
2017-07-01  19:20   A1  11.83983472 
2017-07-02  07:53   A1  11.75332292 
2017-07-02  19:06   A1  11.75332292 
2017-07-03  07:45   A1  11.74469167 
2017-07-03  19:04   A1  11.74469167 
2017-07-04  08:15   A1  11.45409583
```

Thanks!

PS- I haven't tried anything because I can only find example where there is a "start time" and "end time" col. I guess I could create a start time col for each sample and ask r to calculate the time diff between start time and the time of each measurement.... I don't know how to make R make a start time col for the earliest measurement for each sample. I could spend a whole day doing it in excel but there must bet a better solution!

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried. Here is a good starting resource for this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: *"without telling R the start and end time"* ... but in your example, you know end time by the `Date` and `Time` variables, and infer start time based on `lag(Date)` (...). If using `lag()` is not safe, then the answer is almost certainly "no, R cannot know what times the samples were started" :-). If it is safe (my suspicion), then I suggest you transform the two fields `Date` and `Time` into a single `POSIXt` field (e.g., `DateTime`), then use `x <- c(0, diff(DateTime))` and eventually `units(a) <- "hours"`.

Comment: But then I have to manually enter the start time for each of my 50 samples???? I

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. First, unite the `Date` and `Time` column. Then, convert it to a timestamp via `lubridate::ymd_hm`. Next, pluck the first timestamp. Finally, create two new columns that show the difference from that start date.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>%
  unite("datetime", c("Date", "Time"), sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(datetime = ymd_hm(datetime))

start_date <- df$datetime[1]

df %>%
  mutate(time_from_start_secs = datetime - start_date,
         time_from_start_period = seconds_to_period(time_from_start_secs))

#               datetime Sample     Temp time_from_start_secs time_from_start_period
# 1  2017-06-28 13:58:00     A1 13.67870               0 secs                     0S
# 2  2017-06-29 16:08:00     A1 13.34256           94200 secs           1d 2H 10M 0S
# 3  2017-06-30 07:32:00     A1 12.84005          149640 secs          1d 17H 34M 0S
# 4  2017-06-30 19:14:00     A1 12.84005          191760 secs           2d 5H 16M 0S
# 5  2017-07-01 07:40:00     A1 11.83983          236520 secs          2d 17H 42M 0S
# 6  2017-07-01 19:20:00     A1 11.83983          278520 secs           3d 5H 22M 0S
# 7  2017-07-02 07:53:00     A1 11.75332          323700 secs          3d 17H 55M 0S
# 8  2017-07-02 19:06:00     A1 11.75332          364080 secs            4d 5H 8M 0S
# 9  2017-07-03 07:45:00     A1 11.74469          409620 secs          4d 17H 47M 0S
# 10 2017-07-03 19:04:00     A1 11.74469          450360 secs            5d 5H 6M 0S
# 11 2017-07-04 08:15:00     A1 11.45410          497820 secs          5d 18H 17M 0S
```

Alternatively, you could use `min(datetime)`. In addition, if you need to have the calculation "reset" with each `sample`, you will want to use `group_by` -- all in one big swoop we would have:

```
df %>%
  unite("datetime", c("Date", "Time"), sep = " ") %>%
  group_by(Sample) %>%
  mutate(datetime = ymd_hm(datetime),
         time_secs = datetime - min(start_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems a fairly simple data manipulation task. What you are essentially trying is a simple group by and time difference.

The code snippet below does what it takes ::

Step 1: Add date and time to same variable so that we can calculate differences

Step 2: Calculate the difference between current time and minimum time for that group

I updated your data to have the two groups; just to show an example.

```
library(dplyr) # pipes, group by and mutate
library(lubridate) # times 

input_data <- read.table(text = "Date    Time    Sample  Temp
                         2017-06-28  13:58   A1  13.67870139
                         2017-06-29  16:08   A1  13.34256319
                         2017-06-30  07:32   A1  12.84005139
                         2017-06-30  19:14   A1  12.84005139
                         2017-07-01  07:40   A1  11.83983472 
                         2017-07-01  19:20   A1  11.83983472 
                         2017-07-02  07:53   A1  11.75332292 
                         2017-07-02  19:06   A2  11.75332292 
                         2017-07-03  07:45   A2  11.74469167 
                         2017-07-03  19:04   A2  11.74469167 
                         2017-07-04  08:15   A2  11.45409583", 
                         header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(Actual_Time = paste(Date, Time, sep =" ") %>% parse_date_time(., "%y-%m-%d %H:%M")) %>%
  group_by(Sample) %>%
  mutate(Total_Time = difftime(Actual_Time, min(Actual_Time), units = "hours"))
```

## Output

```
# A tibble: 11 x 6
# Groups:   Sample [2]
Date           Time  Sample   Temp       Actual_Time       Total_Time
<chr>         <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>         <dttm>            <time>
 1 2017-06-28 13:58     A1 13.67870 2017-06-28 13:58:00  0.00000 hours
 2 2017-06-29 16:08     A1 13.34256 2017-06-29 16:08:00 26.16667 hours
 3 2017-06-30 07:32     A1 12.84005 2017-06-30 07:32:00 41.56667 hours
 4 2017-06-30 19:14     A1 12.84005 2017-06-30 19:14:00 53.26667 hours
 5 2017-07-01 07:40     A1 11.83983 2017-07-01 07:40:00 65.70000 hours
 6 2017-07-01 19:20     A1 11.83983 2017-07-01 19:20:00 77.36667 hours
 7 2017-07-02 07:53     A1 11.75332 2017-07-02 07:53:00 89.91667 hours
 8 2017-07-02 19:06     A2 11.75332 2017-07-02 19:06:00  0.00000 hours
 9 2017-07-03 07:45     A2 11.74469 2017-07-03 07:45:00 12.65000 hours
10 2017-07-03 19:04     A2 11.74469 2017-07-03 19:04:00 23.96667 hours
11 2017-07-04 08:15     A2 11.45410 2017-07-04 08:15:00 37.15000 hours
```